# How change text and color of button Browse of input file?

Tags: html, css

I design a input file as:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="52"   />
```

[image]

I want to change text and color of button "Browse..". Can you help me? thanks all.

Comment: It is very much browser architecture and OS dependent feature, and it cannot be changed. But you can use plugins.

Comment: Try the answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860865/chrome-css-styling-file-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appearance and functionality is ok, but this is not your real expected one. think this is help to you.

```
 <input type="text" id="fileName" readonly="readonly" >
 <div class="file_input_div" style="display: inline;">
 <input type="button" id="button" value="Open"/>
 <input type="file"  style="opacity:0; position:relative; left:-40px;"  onchange="javascript: document.getElementById ('fileName') . value = this.value"/>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
​#button{
position: relative;
left:-1px;
background-color:#446655;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hrYn2/6/)

Comment: if in your styling i give the width to it that is trying to expand the button  then it is not opening file choose . check here https://jsfiddle.net/smart_tech/w9k6tbu5/

Answer (score 7):

There is the pseudo element `::file-selector-button`.

Use it like:

```css
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  border: 2px solid #6c5ce7;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background-color: #a29bfe;
  transition: 1s;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button:hover {
  background-color: #81ecec;
  border: 2px solid #00cec9;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button

Answer (score 0):

It is very much browser architecture and OS dependent feature, and it cannot be changed.

#### Using an overlay

But you can overlay other elements on top of this and hide the default look. You can also use some plugins, which do this for you.

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) is one such plugin capable of doing it.

**Demo: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/**

Comment: Why the downvotes? This answer part is correct. It cannot be changed. The ONLY way is underlaying the input with some other styled element either directly or via some plugin that does it.

Comment: mmh I'm not the downvoter, but I don't like your answer. Because there is a contradiction: first you say that "it cannot be changed", and after you say that a plugin can do it (a jquery plugin is not a browser plugin, it's simply injection of js, css and html: so it's possible to change it too for us without plugins). I think that your answer can be improved :) (I repeat it: i'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

it is browser architecture dependent. you cant do much about it.

still there are already some discussions about this on stackoverflow

you should check this out

Visit [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Hope this helps

PS: From next time make sure you are not posting a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :
https://codepen.io/claviska/pen/vAgmd

```
<div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
                </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
        </div>



$(function() {
 $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
var input = $(this),
    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
});

 // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

      var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
          log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

      if( input.length ) {
          input.val(log);
      } else {
          if( log ) alert(log);
      }

  });
});

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can found it here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
The post is too long to be copied here.

Basically, you will stylist an `input[type=text]` (which is user will see), and put an `input[type=file] opacity = 0` on top of the `input[type=text]`.

Hope this can help.

For webkit browser only, you can use `CSS` attribute `-webkit-appearance` to clear default style and start to stylist it from the beginning.