# How to change the colour of the browse input type browse button in ie

Tags: html, css

I have used some css to change the background colour of the browse button for
 `<input type="file">`

You can see it here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3vfK/)

The problem I am having is that it does work for chrome (it will show as a black button with white text)

But it will not change the background colour for IE?

I am at a loss with what to do with this to make it work

HTML:

```
<input type="file">
```

CSS:

```
input[type=file] {
border:none !important;
background-color:#F3282B;
background-image:none;
}

input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-appearance: button;
width: 100px;
background:#000 !important;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't support that directly (using CSS only). You can try a workaround like the one explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578749/how-change-text-and-color-of-button-browse-of-input-file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. However, you can hide it and trigger it via js.